# Website article .htaccess 301 redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I have a site in a folder called **patients** and my urls look like so:

http://site.com/patients/**post-name**

http://site.com/patients/articles/**another-post-name**

I want to redirect them all to a clean:

http://newsite.com/**post-name**

http://newsite.com/**another-post-name**

In other words, lose the /articles/ which sometimes appears and 301 to the new site.

Any help on how to do this with htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your .htaccess in http://site.com server and put this(must be the first rule):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule .* http://newsite.com/ [R=301]
```

or

```
Redirect 301 / http://newsite.com/
```

Regards.

Comment: If the incoming URL is `http://site.com/patients/post-name`, for example, it will be redirected to `http://newsite.com/`, but what about the rest of the URI `/post-name`?